# How do I properly utilize datatriggers and setters when using dependency properties in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatrigger

I am trying to create a generic status indicator display for a WPF HMI application.  These status indicators are a user control wherein two concentric circles of different radius overlap.  I want to be able to change the colour of the "fill" property on the path tag depending on some dependency properties of my `StatusIndicator` class. In practice, there are an arbitrary number of these indicators that may be used.  The 'state' of these indicators is handled by a class object, `DigitalIOAssignment`, which gets its data (componentID, isActive, isInterlocked, etc.) from a PLC concerning the state of a given I/O component.  Since the number of these status indicators is arbitrary, I create a `List <DigitalIOAssignment>` and pass this to my viewmodel.  This is working correctly and I can see the data I want to bind correctly in my viewmodel.

The status indicator is coded as follows:

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="HMI.UserControls.StatusIndicator"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"              
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMI.UserControls" 
            xmlns:globals="clr-namespace:HMI.LogixPLCService.Globals;assembly=HMI.LogixPLCService" 
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Viewbox x:Name="ControlViewbox" Stretch="Uniform" Height="auto" Width="auto">
        <Canvas x:Name="ControlCanvas" Width="100" Height="100">
            <!-- Draw Secondary Indicator Body First -->
            <Path x:Name="StatusIndicator_Body" Width="100" Height="100" 
                  Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" StrokeThickness="1"
                  StrokeMiterLimit="2.75" Stroke="Black">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
                </Path.Data>
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:StatusIndicator}}, Path=isInterlockedProperty}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
            <!-- Draw Foreground Indicator Body Second -->
            <Path x:Name="StatusIndicator_Status" Width="100" Height="100" 
                  Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" StrokeThickness=".5"
                  StrokeMiterLimit="1" Stroke="Black">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30"/>
                </Path.Data>
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:StatusIndicator}}, Path=isActiveProperty}" 
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
namespace HMI.UserControls
{
    public partial class StatusIndicator : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for StatusIndicator.xaml
        ///</summary>
        public string StatusIndicatorName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(StatusIndicatorNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusIndicatorNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusIndicatorNameProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("StatusIndicatorName", 
                typeof(string), typeof(StatusIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string ComponentID
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ComponentIDProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ComponentIDProperty, value); }
        }
    
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ComponentIDProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("ComponentID", 
                typeof(string), typeof(StatusIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public bool isActiveProperty
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(isActive); }
            set { SetValue(isActive, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty isActive = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("isActiveProperty", 
                typeof(bool), typeof(StatusIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool isInterlockedProperty
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(isInterlocked); }
            set { SetValue(isInterlocked, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty isInterlocked = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("isInterlockedProperty", 
                typeof(bool), typeof(StatusIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public StatusIndicator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In my view's xaml, I create each status indicator in the designer and hard-code a `x:Name` to it and assign this to `StatusIndicatorName` since I can't figure out how to pass this Name value at runtime to the code-behind (any hints would be appreciated!!).  What I want to do is this:

1. Create a StatusIndicator user control and assign the `StatusIndicatorName` property a known string
2. `UserControls:StatusIndicator.ComponentID` property is bound to `DigitalIOAssignment.componentID`
3. It is my hope that binding to the List causes an iteration over this list and to engage a  `<DataTrigger>` that will allow me to reference the same `DigitalIOAssignment` object when the trigger condition is met, and set the appropriate flags (isActive, isInterlocked etc) in this way.  This pseudocode represents, I hope, what I am trying to do in my view's Xaml:

```xml
<UserControls:StatusIndicator x:Name="DI_99VLV01"
                              StatusIndicatorName="{Binding ElementName=DI_99VLV01}"                                      
                              Height="18" Width="18"
                              Margin="106,144,0,0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"       
                              ComponentID="{Binding privateDigitalInputAssignments/componentID}">
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(UserControls:StatusIndicator.ComponentID)}"
                 Value="{Binding Path=(UserControls:StatusIndicator.StatusIndicatorName)}">
        <Setter Property="UserControls:StatusIndicator.isActiveProperty"
                Value="{Binding privateDigitalInputAssignments/isActive}"/>
        <Setter Property="UserControls:StatusIndicator.isInterlockedProperty" 
                Value="{Binding privateDigitalInputAssignments/isInterlocked}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</UserControls:StatusIndicator>
```

Obviously, this implementation does not work.  I cannot use a binding for a value on a data trigger (I may have to hard-code the component ID I am expecting since I hard-code the status indicator name anyway), and I cannot seem to use setters for my dependency properties.  I get an error:

`Cannot find the static member 'isActivePropertyProperty' [sic!] on the type 'StatusIndicator'.`

Can someone please give me some insight how to approach this problem for what I am trying to achieve? Even if I need to start over and approach it a different way?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're after. You have an arbitrary number of `DigitalIOAssignment`'s which are held in a List in the VM, and you want to create a `StatusIndicator` in the view for each of them?

The usual way to do this is use an `ItemsControl` in the view, with a `DataTemplate` that has a single `StatusIndicator`. If you bind `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to your list, wpf will apply the template for every item in the list, and the `DataContext` of the template will be that item, so you can do straight bindings with no need for triggers.

Something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DigitalInputAssignments}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

      <UserControls:StatusIndicator Height="18" Width="18"
                                    Margin="106,144,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    StatusIndicatorName="{Binding Name}"
                                    ComponentID="{Binding ComponentID}"
                                    IsActive="{Binding IsActive}"
                                    IsInterlocked="{Binding IsInterlocked}">
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gaz!  Your assessment is correct: I have an arbitrary number of DigitalIOAssignments (number is based on some arrays in a PLC) and have an arbitrary (but not necessarily equal) number of status indicators depending on what is required to display; I would add these to the xaml manually for a given project and want to give them identifying names in the xaml.  When I try this method with an ItemsControl, it is not clear how I am supposed to differentiate specific StatusIndicators.  The DigitalIOAssignment has no knowledge of the view or how many indicators I am showing.

Comment: If you require specific indicators on the view, then just expose specific DigitalIOAssignments as properties on your VM and bind them individually. That's the whole point of a VM, to manipulate model data into a data structure that represents the view.